# CSS line-height on inline element

Tags: html, css

is it possible to change the line-height within a paragraph?

for example, if i have a paragraph or div or label set at a particular font-size & line-height, and need the last part of that text to be smaller, i can do a span within the p or div and change the font-size just fine, but any adjustments to the line-height do not work.

i know i can just change the span to a block or inline-block, but then that wraps the text under that paragraph. i'd like to keep the text running inline if possible.

example @ https://jsfiddle.net/fye8bcjx/

```css
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 2;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
---
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.
  <span>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.
        </span>
</p>
```

Comment: well, you have already the answer within your question .. but the real question is why you want this ?

Comment: How do you expect to have 2 different line heights on the same line of text? How would that work?

Comment: Add `background` to your span to see its `line-height`: https://jsfiddle.net/fye8bcjx/13/ It seems unchanged because of default `vertical-align:baseline`

Comment: the reason is to have some clarifying text to a form label. like `<label>Where will you be staying while in town? <span>please provide an address and local phone number</span></label>` the span part is smaller text, but when it wraps, the line-height puts it far away from the text above it. does that make sense?

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you are making a list of tag blocks for example. Plenty of use cases. See my answer :)

Comment: @Alexus here it's not a question of different blocks ;) in this case it's trivial ... he want all the text to be one block

Comment: Here is an interesting exploration into @KoshVery reply - experimentation with vertical-align. https://jsfiddle.net/fye8bcjx/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line height on the block container, (the `<p>` element in this case) gives the minimum line height for the lines it contains. So if you want the smaller text to be closer together, you need to avoid setting a large line-height for that. Instead, use the line-heights of the inline elements:

```css
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 0;
}

span.primary {
  line-height: 2;
}

span.secondary {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
---
<p><span class="primary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.</span>
  <span class="secondary">Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.
        </span>
</p>
```

Comment: hey, this is great, but check out what happens if there's more text to cause a 3rd line to wrap of the secondary span. when the end of the first span & the beginning of the second are on the same line, it's like the whole block ends up having 3 different line-heights. hmmm. https://jsfiddle.net/fye8bcjx/27

Comment: nevermind - just tweaking the line-heights & font-sizes to be more readable & less example oriented did the trick. so THANK YOU for this solution!!!

Answer (score -1):

[UPDATE] This answer is indeed not solving OPs problem. I will look for another solution.

Yes, of course. **Inline block** is exactly for that. It has most of the properties of a block, but acts like an inline element.

```
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 2;
}
span {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block; /* <=== Inline block to the rescue. */
}
```

Comment: and you read the question clearly :) `i know i can just change the span to a block or inline-block, but then that wraps the text under that paragraph. i'd like to keep the text running inline if possible.` ... run the snippet with bigger content and you will see what happen ;)

Comment: Ah, got it. You are right! Let me see if I can comeback with something :)